# Understanding the definition of the direct sum of subspaces of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, direct-sum

I have a question regarding the definition of direct sum of a vector space in relation to subspaces.

> **Definition:** A vector space $V$ is called the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$ and $W_1 + W_2 = V$. We denote that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ by writing $V = W_1\oplus W_2$.

Is this definition saying that any vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the set $W_1 + W_2$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is saying that any vector $v \in V$ can be written as $v = w_1 + w_2$ where $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_2$ (this is the condition $W_1 + W_2 = V$), and this decomposition is unique (this follows from the condition $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$). You don't need to take linear combinations.

Comment: Right, the key word missing from the OPs statement is "unique".  Of course what the OP says is true, it does mean any vector can be written as a combination like that.  But it's not equivalent to that without specifying "unique".

Answer (score 1):

1. $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ if and only if
   \begin{align}
   \phi\colon W_1\times W_2&\to V\\
   (v,w)&\mapsto v+w
   \end{align}
   is injective and
2. $V=W_1+W_2$ if and only if $\phi$ is surjective.

In summary:
\begin{equation}
V=W_1\oplus W_2\Leftrightarrow \phi\text{ is a vector space isomorphism.}
\end{equation}

In other words: $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ **if and only if** for all $v\in V$, there is exactly one $(w_1,w_2)\in W_1\times W_2$ such that $v=w_1+w_2$.

**Proof** of 1.:

(Reminder: If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces of $V$, $W_1\cap W_2$ is also a vector subspace of $V$.)

- If $v\in W_1\cap W_2$, $\phi(v,0)=v+0=v=0+v=\phi(0,v)$. $\Rightarrow v=0$ if $\phi$ is injective.
- Conversely, if $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ and $(v,w),(v',w')\in W_1\times W_2$, then
  \begin{equation}
  \phi(v,w)=\phi(v',w')\Leftrightarrow v+w=v'+w'\Leftrightarrow v-v'=w'-w=:u.
  \end{equation}
  Since $v-v'\in W_1$ and $w'-w\in W_2$, $u\in W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$. Thus, $v=v'$ and $w=w'$.